# Как в JavaScript, достать имя кнопки на которую только что нажали?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, события, click

Всем привет, 
Помогите пожалуйста решит вопрос.
 1. Как достать имя кнопки на которую только что нажали и поместить его в alert?
`function sayStyle() {
            alert("You pressed on the button" + "Имя кнопки");
        }`

2. И потом также поместить значения id етой кнопки в документ. `function addText() {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The style was changed to" + "здесь должно бить имя id кнопки";
   }`

   Спасибо зарание.

Ниже приведен весь код -

```js
(function(){
        var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
        var myFunc = function() {
            if (this.id === "day") {
                document.body.className = "day"
            }else if (this.id === "night") {
                document.body.className = "night"
            }
        };
        function sayStyle() {
            alert("You pressed on the button" + );
        }
        function addText() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The style was changed to" + ;
        }
        for (var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++) {
            buttons[i].addEventListener("click", myFunc);
            buttons[i].addEventListener("click", sayStyle);
            buttons[i].addEventListener("click", addText);
        };
    })();
```

```css
h3 {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif
        }
        button {
            padding: 10px;
            width: 70px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        button:hover {
            background-color: #ccc;
            transition: 350ms ease-in;
        }
        button:first-of-type {
            margin-left: 15%;
        }
        .day {
            background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
            color: #474747;
        }
        .night {
            background-color: #474747;
            color: #fff;
        }
```

```html
<body class="day">
    <h3>Press the button</h3>
    <button id="day">Day</button>
    <button id="night">Night</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function(){
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
    var myFunc = function(e) {
        if (this.id === "day") {
            document.body.className = "day"
        }else if (this.id === "night") {
            document.body.className = "night"
        }
    };
    function sayStyle(e) {
        alert("You pressed on the button " + e.target.id);
    }
    function addText(e) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The style was changed to " + e.target.id;
    }
    for (var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", myFunc);
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", sayStyle);
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", addText);
    };
})();
```

```html
<h3>Press the button</h3>
    <button id="day">Day</button>
    <button id="night">Night</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

В случае, когда для добавление обработчика события используется [*addEventListener*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Внутри обработчика `this` указывается на элемент, связанный с этим обработчиком.

В данном случае это будет нужная кнопка.

Любопытно, что в *myFunc* данный подход уже используется. Непонятно, что мешало применить его в двух остальных функциях.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
var myFunc = function() {
  if (this.id === "day") {
    document.body.className = "day"
  } else if (this.id === "night") {
    document.body.className = "night"
  }
};

function sayStyle() {
  console.log("You pressed on the button " + this.id);
}

function addText() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The style was changed to " + this.id;
}
for (var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", myFunc);
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", sayStyle);
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", addText);
};
```

```css
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: 350ms ease-in;
}

button:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 15%;
}

.day {
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  color: #474747;
}

.night {
  background-color: #474747;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body class="day">
  <h3>Press the button</h3>
  <button id="day">Day</button>
  <button id="night">Night</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```